# Determining Path of MultipartFile in Groovy

Tags: grails

My Grails app is successfully uploading then parsing a **MultipartFile** with the following code:

```
def file = request.getFile('rawReport')
def report = new XmlSlurper().parse(file.inputStream)
```

**My Problem:**  I need the path of the original file ('rawReport'), can see path information in the Debugger's "Expression" View, but can't find a method that will return the file's path as I need it.

I've found loads of "methods of the sort I'd like to have" [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/JN2015-File) but they're all for simple Files, not MultipartFiles.  I felt a surge of hope when I found "getStorageDescription" for MultipartFiles [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html) but that hope was dashed when it returned "in memory" (literally... what good is that?!)

It's frustrating because I can see pieces of what I could use in the debugger... STS Expression View:  Name:file -> repository -> path "\\home$\Happiness\Awaits\You\Here..."

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's not available as described in the Javadoc for the `getOriginalFilename()` method: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html#getOriginalFilename%28%29

I'm guessing that this is a security issue. I found that it behaved for me as described for Firefox and Chrome, and even Opera didn't include the full path. So even if you can get the information locally you wouldn't be able to trust that the full path would be available in general.

You might look for a Flash-based uploader which wouldn't be constrained by browser restrictions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and suggestion.  I'll research candidate plug-ins but must agree with your assumption about exposed paths leading to security vulnerabilities.  My application is not web-based, however, and I _do_ have some control over the selection of browsers that users might employ.  But, still, **we cannot depend on that which we don't control 100%...**  (And, unfortunately, there's nothing I can control 100% of the time.)  Thanks again!.